# RegEx split with grouping

Tags: regex, perl, powershell, split

Is there some caveat to using grouping with split operations?

In perl:

```
print join("|",split(m/(A|AND)/,"foo A bar"))."\n";
```

Expected:

```
foo | bar
```

Output:

```
foo |A| bar
```

Identical expected/output for Powershell:

```
([regex]::Split("foo A bar","(A|AND)"))-join"|"
```

Seems the problem arises when using grouping--without parentheses all is well:

```
([regex]::Split("foo A bar","A|B"))-join"|"
```

Output is as expected:

```
foo | bar
```

But when I introduce grouping to be able to use multi-character alternations (surround by a padding character - "\s(A|AND)\s"), the split starts behaving unexpectedly.

What is split actually doing here--what kind of split is being performed? Why is the split I might expect not being performed? What are my alternatives?

Comment: Yep, the capture groups produce an element in the array of the captured data. Use `(?:A|B)` to elminate the delimeter. Having this ability though is very powerfull. For instance you can filter and split at the same time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use non capturing parentheses for split regex, `(?:..)`

```
print join("|",split(m/(?:A|AND)/,"foo A bar"))."\n";
```

From [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html),

> If the PATTERN contains capturing groups, then for each separator, an additional field is produced for each substring captured by a group (in the order in which the groups are specified, as per backreferences); if any group does not match, then it captures the undef value instead of a substring.

Same goes for PowerShell (or rather .Net). From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yttk7sy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> If capturing parentheses are used in a Regex.Split expression, any captured text is included in the resulting string array. For example, if you split the string "plum-pear" on a hyphen placed within capturing parentheses, the returned array includes a string element that contains the hyphen.

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe i didn't know about non-capturing parentheses!